# How to identify why two-factor SMS messages are never received from certain websites

Tags: authentication, sms, two-factor-authentication, multi-factor-authentication

I have accounts with three financial websites which only offer two-factor authentication codes to be sent via text message or phone call, but when I request codes via text message, the messages are never received. When I choose the phone call option, however, I do receive the call.

Troubleshooting steps taken:

- Requesting codes multiple times does not solve the issue - I never receive any texts.
- I've verified that I have not blocked any phone numbers, either on my phone's local settings or within my account with my cellular carrier.
- I can receive codes from all other websites on which I use two-factor authentication and receive codes via text message. This only happens with these three websites. Also, there is no relation between these three sites - they are all for completely separate financial institutions.
- Reaching out to the customer service/technical support departments of these three websites or my cellular carrier has not produced any helpful information or solutions.

I want to be able to figure out why this happens and make it so I can receive texts, so that in the event that the phone call option is removed or temporarily unavailable for any of these sites, or I start using a new site which also has this issue but does not offer the phone call option, I won't lose access to my accounts.

How else could I troubleshoot this problem?

Also, I posted this question in the Information Security Stack Exchange site because it relates to multi-factor authentication but someone closed the question because they felt it was not related to security.

Comment: Check the junk SMS messages on your phone.  Android and iOS both have the abuse to filter what they believe to be junk SMS messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving this issue by contacting my cellular provider again, but this time immediately after requesting a code from one of the sites. A representative I spoke with confirmed that they saw the blocked message and that it was from having a "short code blacklist" set on my number (["short codes" explained here](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Short_code)). They removed that and now I'm able to get the SMS messages again.

Answer (score 0):

You should contact the service provider (ie the website you are using).   There is simply no way for you to do anything else.

There are multiple ways to send SMS codes from multiple providers.

If there is any guarantee of delivery of SMS messages it is to the service provider (who is likely paying for them) and not to you.  Because there is (hopefully) a commercial relationship with the service provider and the SMS provider, there will (a) likely be some logs - because, billing   and (b) A mechanism for escallation - because its a paid service - and if not, well, its worth the cost.

It is likely the issue is an interconnect between Telco networks.